# Troubles with FindObjectOfType

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple damage boost I have 2 scripts, one attached to the projectile and one to the booster

Projectile:

```cs
public class DamageDealer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public int damage = 25;

    public int GetDamage() 
    {
        return damage;
    }

    public void Hit()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void IncreaseDamage(int value)
    {
        damage += value;
        Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Booster:

```cs
public class DamageUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    int damageBoost = 50;
    DamageDealer damageDealer;

    void Awake()
    {
        damageDealer = FindObjectOfType<DamageDealer>();

        Debug.Log(damageDealer); // this returns as null
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            damageDealer.IncreaseDamage(damageBoost);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the Booster I've already identified what's returning as null, but I'm quite new to *unity* and *C#* so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Some more info the Projectile is a prefab while the Booster is not (yet)
scripts are attached and enabled, objects are enabled too.

`Hit()` and `GetDamage()` are for another script I have no issue with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wont find a prefab only instantiated and enabled GameObjects

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to find the object before it's instantiated, change the `Awake` to `Start` or try to change [Script Execution Order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Check Also; [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: It is true, when i fire the projectile it changes from null to the clone of the projectile
Should i make a separate Script to manage firepower?
I would like to upvote you but i can't yet

Comment: You should get DamegeDealer component via  `Component.TryGetComponent` when `OnTriggerEnter2D` happens. You should not store reference of other classes most of the time. You should check SOLID principles and design patterns.

Comment: you're absolutely right, consider i'm just 3 months into learnig unity and c# especially.
Thanks a lot for your help, i can't wait to look back at this post and smile

Comment: @oistikbal _"You should get ...component via ... when OnTriggerEnter2D happens....You should not store reference of other classes most of the time"_ - disagree for **1)** for games you generally want to perform initialisation including lookups at the start of a level and avoid it whilst playing (unless provider objects are short-lived) for performance reasons **2)** _SOLID, dependency injection_ and other Windoze business software mantra and religions have no place in game development.  We want speed & efficiency not writing code that keeps static code analysis tools happy.

Comment: _"You should not store reference of other classes most of the time"_ - that is a pretty-broad statement.   So my `Person` class can't have a `private string _name` field?

Comment: What i mean with references, other objects that doesn't related with the object direclty. if the "_name" is the actual property of the object itself it's totaly right but if it is other object's name it's not ok, that's my preference. Writing fastand effiency code not the always the best sceneraio, i'm completly disaggree with you. if you're writing good and maintable code, you can write fast and effiency code still but if you're can't you wont able to write good code when you need.

Comment: That's generally what i've seen from game development ecosystem, we're all trying to do game without knowing basics. I don't even support learning programming through game developement especially with game engines.

Comment: _"What i mean with references, other objects that doesn't related with the object direclty"_ - **aggregation** as in  _["A Company is an **aggregation** of People"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61527/125248)_ is one of the pillars of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships).   Aggregation in this case means the `Person` exists when the `Company` closes but by the same token **it does not mean** that `Company` **is not allowed to store links** to `Person` whilst it is operating.  Otherwise UML diagrams around the world would lose most of the lines.

Comment: _"Writing fastand effiency code not the always the best sceneraio"_ - nonsense.  So back in the 80s where **all** games were written in assembly language everyone new that depending on the equivalent of a `for loop`, if you "unwound" your tight loop, repeating the statement before performing the counter compare, it led to significantly faster performance.  [I should know, I was one of them.](https://www.cocopedia.com/wiki/index.php/Xenion)  It was not too long ago that we in the XNA world learnt to replace C# `foreach` with `for` because the latter lead to measurable garbage collection.

Comment: _"we're all trying to do game without knowing basics"_ - **I completely agree with you there**. :)  Quite often there are questions on Stack Overflow that are quite clearly beginner C# questions and that is totally fine.  _We are all learning, something, somewhere, sometime._  I agree too that starting off learning C# and a gaming middleware like Unity or Unreal at the same time might be too much.   I can understand the attraction though.  I don't claim to know everything; I know there are things that I don't know; and I know there are unknown unknowns. :)

Comment: Yes you're right but not totally, do you think we need that much optimisation anymore  especially with new hardware except AAA games? Let him know the basics, let him be a better engineer then he will be able to decide what he needs but i don't think someone who doesn't even know those basic things will able to what you say. Have you ever looked at the most of the unity games that developed by indie developers? All of them spagetti, not because they're doing for performance because they don't even know the basics.

Comment: You're right with aggeration etc stuff, but most of the time the storage of the references are not necessary. i wanted to give him that habit.

Comment: Yes some good points there too. :)